# Seqeulize - Create new relationship record from existing instance with hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

New to sequelize and I cannot seem to find in the docs on what I am looking for. Everything in the docs I see shows me how to create a new DB record and its association together, if they are both being created. What I am looking for is I already have an instance of a `User` and I just want to add a new notes record have have it automatically enter the userId FK for me in the notes table.
I have a background in PhP and Laravel and the equivalent of what I am trying to do would be (in laravel) something like:

```
// Laravel version of what I am trying to accomplish in sequelize
$user = User::find($request->user);
$user->notes()->create([
  'note' => 'Hello World'
]); // Inserts record in notes table with FK of user id
```

What I tried in sequelize (not working obviously) is:

```
const user = await User.findByPk(req.body.user, {
  include: ['notes']
});
const result = await user.notes.create({ note: 'Hello World' }); // not working, definitely the wrong way to do it
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Did you try something like `await user.addNote({ note: 'Hello World' })`?

Answer (score 0):

With guidance from the comment made by @Anatoly I was able to get on the right track.

What I was looking for is:

```
const result = await user.createNote({ note: 'Hello World' });
```